# transform.Rotate with z clamped to 0

Tags: c#, unity

I have a virtual joystick to rotate the player and this piece of code works nice and smooth for the rotation of the players view.

```
public void rotatePlayer(Vector3 newPosition){
  transform.Rotate(new Vector3(-newPosition.y,newPosition.x,0)*Time.deltaTime);
}
```

I pass a Vector3 with the position of the joystick in relation of his parrent's(the joystick border) anchor.That gives me the rotation direction.Which means that if I set the rotation of the camera direclty it will just flip to that point and not move progresively to that point.

Even though z is set to 0 in the vector3, it changes the z axis angle of the camera. How can I clamp it to 0 without using many resources?

I tried other methods but they just switch the camera's rotation directly when the joystick is touched like I already said.Flip and stop.

I guess I could just set the z axis rotation to 0 every time but that just seems like double work.

Comment: Does this only happen if the camera's rotation is already different from the default or does it always happen?

Comment: Always.The x and y axis rotation affects the z rotation as much as I understand and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use localEulerAngles instead

```
float rotationX = transform.localEulerAngles.x + amount to rotate x;
float rotationY = transform.localEulerAngles.y + amount to rotate y;
transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(rotationX, rotationY, 0);
```

Comment: When the joystick is moved and the PointerEvenetData changes it just jumps to that point, it doesn't move progresively to that point it just jumps to it.I need a slow rotation towards a point.Changing the eulerangules all the time even with a little bit serously drops the fps for some reason.I asume it could be my fault.

Comment: Updated the example code. I don't think rotating your camera should lower your FPS